# Should we add Music ID to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, music-identification

We've gotten a little influx of Music ID questions as of late.  I was wondering if we should specifically add Music Identification to the off-topic section of the [FAQ](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq).

Maybe changing it to:

**Please note that the following subjects are considered *off-topic* here:**

- Distribution
- Movie/TV purchasing/viewing locations
- The operation of playing a movie whether it be digital or physical format.
- Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
- **Music Identification**
- TV news and current affairs
- A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
- Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

There might be a better way to word it, but that's the general gist of my thoughts.

---

List of recently closed music id questions:

- [Awake Pilot ending song](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9588/awake-pilot-ending-song)
- [Name of the opera music in American Horror Story](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/whats-the-name-of-the-opera-music-in-american-horror-story-2x10)
- [Electronic Piece in American Dad](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8995/whats-the-electronic-piece-in-american-dads-national-treasure-4-baby-franny)
- [What songs has lyle lovett performed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/what-songs-has-lyle-lovett-performed-on-conan-obrien)
- [What other movies use this song](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/what-other-movie-uses-this-moody-synthesizer-song-from-extracted-2012)
- [Music when Barney is absent minded](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/what-is-the-music-that-fades-in-when-barney-stinson-is-absent-minded)

Comment: Good Idea ......

Comment: [Previous discussion on music identification](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/398/should-questions-about-which-artist-sang-or-played-a-song-or-music-in-a-movie-be)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [Robert](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/855) that adding this to the list would make it a bit unwieldy.  That list of items is getting pretty big.  If Music Identification is to be added, I'd recommend that you take this time to also consolidate that list a bit.  Several of those items overlap, and could better be summed up in a short, general statement.  Namely:

- These all deal with how/when movies are available, and could be combined into a general 'where to buy or shopping questions'

  1. Distribution
  2. Movie/TV purchasing/viewing locations
  3. A title's release date
- I think these could be combined into a 'current events' sort of item:

  1. TV news and current affairs
  2. rumors about a specific title or series.

With these consolidated, you get a shorter list of items that give a quicker impression of what is off-topic.

Comment: I completely agree with the first point.  I think TV news is not the same about rumours.  We could have (1) Where to buy or shopping, (2) Rumours about a movie or series and (3) TV news and current affairs.

Comment: @iandotkelly, Agreed completely. But we must _add_ it. Also it would not be bad if we add hyperlinks of an ideal off-topic question of each category!

Comment: @Mistu4u Adding links to off-topic questions is basically impossible.  Off-topic questions would all be closed and eventually deleted, so there's nothing to link to.

Comment: @Keen, Ooo, did not know that they get deleted eventually!

Answer (score 1):

You're running a bit into *"bulleted list from hell"* territory here. I'd be *disinclined* to add this unless it becomes a frequent and prominent problem.

Creating a long list of all the ways you can go wrong on this site is somewhat user hostile. The two lists (what belongs, what doesn't) is there to convey the *gist* of what this site is about. Certainly you know better than I, but this additions looks a bit reactionary. Wait until there's a problem you feel warrants **announcing to *every* new member of your community** when they first come to visit.

When you tell 80% of your audience something that only affects 0.020% of your participants, that's where the *"all the rules you can break"* list goes bad.

Comment: I added a list of the most recent questions that have been closed for music id.  It goes to early december.

Comment: It would not be a great feeling for a newcomer either to ask his 1st question and soon it gets closed being off-topic, although it isn't explicitly written in the FAQ!

Comment: @Mistu4u Unfortunately, that's where the problem begins; the belief that if you just continue to enumerate all the ways you can suck at Stack Exchange, **that** will avoid ill feelings and problems. Except it usually just has the opposite effect. Thoughtfully providing guidance for the  **occasional problem** will trump *"didn't you read the faq"* any day. I don't have a hard-lined opinion on this discussion, specifically. It just seemed premature, so I'm pointing this out on a cautionary note.

Comment: +1 Hmmh, also a good point. In fact too detailed a list could lead to the list loosing its *example*-character. People might post off-topic things because they're not *explicitly* on the *forbidden-list*.

Answer (score 1):

If music identification questions are decided to be *off-topic* then let it be posted in the FAQ section. In fact we should not delay it. I think new users are taking it granted anything related to movies can be asked here and also movie-identification question played catalyst in asking music-ID questions. So we should explicitly write it in the FAQ. It would not be a hearty welcome for a new user if his question is closed without any prior notice from the FAQ.

Comment: I would like to share my experience here with seasoned advice. Where it is not written explicitly that recipe request is OT and my question got closed although I searched FAQ before posting. So then one of an avid users forced to [comment](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29791/please-share-with-me-the-method-of-making-daal-tadka) `yes, the FAQ could be made clearer`. I don't want our community to be embarassed such a way here!

Comment: off-topic and on-topic and both be abbreviated as OT.  Which do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that is true. I mean Off topic. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @DForck42, Actually [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie) it is written OT is _Off-Topic_.

Comment: meh, that's one site's definition.  I've always seen it typed out everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Music identification is off-topic? [The policy doesn't seem to be consistently applied](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/what-is-the-whistled-tune-from-american-horror-story) then.

The questions you listed were all downvoted and closed, but mine ended up with 5 upvotes. It sounds like there's more discussion to be had among the community on whether or not these questions are acceptable before you/we talk about modifying the FAQ.

Comment: Just as a side note, I did not agree on up-voting the question. I don't know why it had got up-votes. But one reason maybe it is a lot easy to find songs in a movie than tunes.

Comment: @Mistu4u That's entirely possible. I also have no problem with it being closed if it is off-topic. I'm just saying that it seems to me that there isn't actual consensus on that just yet.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that one.  I'll leave it alone until we have more of a concensus of the validity of music id questions on the site.  I was under the impression they were off-topic, maybe I got confused.